# Javascript order of operations issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

I have over two hundred web pages that need a lightbox added to them. I've added a javascript file at the bottom of the `<body>` for these pages. Unfortunately, I forgot to add JQuery in the `<head>`...I'm hating myself for this :(.

Basically, I'm creating and appending the `<script>` and `<link>` tags to the `<head>` of my html from my javascript file at the bottom of my `<body>`

I believe that since I'm loading the script tags from the end of my HTML that it's an order of operations problem.

When I click on the designated tag defined by the shadowbox plugin, nothing happens.

I'm a little stuck on this one if anyone could help. I'd really appreciate it!

Here is some example code that I'm using:

```
//Get head element
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

//Create and attach JQuery
var jquery = document.createElement('script');

jquery.type = 'text/javascript';
jquery.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
jquery.onload = function() { 
};
head.insertBefore(jquery,head.childNodes[4]);

//Create and attach shadowbox CSS
var shadowboxCSS = document.createElement('link');
shadowboxCSS.type = 'text/css';
shadowboxCSS.rel = 'stylesheet';
shadowboxCSS.href = 'http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/shadowboxCSS.css';
head.appendChild(shadowboxCSS);

//Create and attach shadowbox JS
var shadowbox = document.createElement('script');

shadowbox.type = 'text/javascript';
shadowbox.src = 'http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/shadowboxJS.js';
head.appendChild(shadowbox);

//Call shadowbox function in head
var shadowboxcall = document.createElement('script');
shadowboxcall.type = 'text/javascript';
shadowboxcall.innerHTML = "Shadowbox.init()";
head.appendChild(shadowboxcall);
```

Comment: so... what is the actual error?

Comment: Have you tried moving your shadow box related code into the `jquery.onload`?

Comment: It's not very clear from your question exactly what the problem is.  Code not working?  Error?  Please be more descriptive of the behavior you're wanting but not getting.

Comment: It's not raising an error. The code just won't execute in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry about that. The question is if this is an order of operations error. Since I'm adding the jquery and the plugin from a script file at the end of my HTML.

Comment: I have added the shadow box related code to the 'jquery.onload' event, but I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "call shadowbox function" section, it's not right.

Instead, add `shadowbox.onload = function() {Shadowbox.init();};` to the end.

Comment: WOOOOOOT! That did it...Thanks for your help! I was looking for a better way to call this function, and this makes perfect sense.